# Persistent system freezing issue on Debian, Mint, and Ubuntu

Tags: linux, debian, linux-mint, freeze, crash

I know the problem seems to be quite abstract, but let me explain what's going on.

First of all, keep in mind that my notebook is a Dell 3567, seventh generation i5, 16 GB of RAM, and a 256 GB SSD. That is, it is not a problem of lack of capacity.

Before, when my notebook had only 4 GB of RAM, it didn't give these freezes and reported an error asking if I wanted to force stop.

Well, I'm currently using Debian 11, but these crashes happened on Mint and Ubuntu too. I install the operating system, and after a while, it starts freezing out of nowhere. And they are with simple tasks.

When I have a browser window reading a blog, the site freezes, and the system asks if I want to "force stop." Something must be going on because it's not a lack of RAM, and I'm not doing complex tasks. The system just freezes.

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on?

Comment: So you replaced the 4 GB in the laptop with one or a couple of new RAM modules to bring it up to 16 GB? Have you run some memory diagnostic software?  You use the word "crash" and "freeze", but you only describe a "freeze" of a single piece of software, not of the whole system (or it would not be able to ask you to "force stop" the offending application).

Comment: Well, first of all, English is not my primary language, so I believe I must have used the terms "crash" and "freeze" wrong. And yes! I changed my RAM memory to two 8 GB sticks. And I didn't use any memory diagnostic software. Should I do that and send it here? And how do you do it?